# How can I pass curl options through Python requests?

Tags: python, curl, salesforce, python-requests

I am working with the Desk.com api.  One of the limitations is that they only allow 500 pages of records to be called.  If you have more than 500 pages that need to be downloaded, it is necessary to sort/filter the data with the curl -d option. Typically, I do this by setting the 'since_id' option to a higher ID and downloading 500 more pages.  This is essentially telling the desk database to send me up to 500 pages of data since_id=x

Typically I run this in python using os.popen(), but I want to try to switch it over to requests.get(), as that is something that should work better on windows devices.

```
os.popen("curl https://www.URL.com -u username:password -H 'Accept:application/json' -d 'since_id=someID&sort_field=id&sort_direction=asc' -G")
```

With requests, I have tried running it many different ways including trying to pass the -d parameters through like so.

```
payload = '-d 'since_id=someID&sort_field=id&sort_direction=asc' -G'
payload(alternate) = "{"-d":"'since_id=someID&sort_field=id&sort_direction=asc'","-G":""}"
requests.get('https://www.URL.com',auth=('username','password'),data=payload)
```

Honestly, I wasn't sure what to do with the -G at the end of my second attempt at the payload variable.

```
I have tried the following.
    *including '-G' in the "-d" value of the json as well as putting it in its own dict
    *a few different variations including switching 'data' to 'params' on the requests.get line.
    *Adding/removing single quotes on the -d value in the get request
```

Comment: Why don't you: 1. read the CURL docs to actually understand what those flags **actually do**; then 2. read the request docs to see how the same functionality should be implemented? Believe it or not, for example, `-d`, while a perfectly sensible command line flag, is generally not going to be a key in your request headers or JSON body.

Answer (score 0):

The `-d` argument in curl corresponds to query parameters in requests. Something like this should work:

```
payload = {'since_id': 'someID', 'sort_field': 'id', 'sort_direction': 'asc'}
requests.get('https://www.example.com', params=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the api uses basic authentication.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
payload = {'something':'value'}
requests.get('http://myurl.com', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'), params=Payload)
```

Hopefully this will work!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to POST which is `requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)`

Full example

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080 \
   -H "Content-Type: application/cloudevents+json" \
   -d '{
    "specversion" : "1.0",
    "type" : "example.com.cloud.event",
    "source" : "https://example.com/cloudevents/pull",
    "subject" : "123",
    "id" : "A234-1234-1234",
    "time" : "2018-04-05T17:31:00Z",
    "data" : "hello world"
}'
```

```
import requests
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/cloudevents+json'}
data = {
    "specversion" : "1.0",
    "type" : "example.com.cloud.event",
    "source" : "https://example.com/cloudevents/pull",
    "subject" : "123",
    "id" : "A234-1234-1234",
    "time" : "2018-04-05T17:31:00Z",
    "data" : "hello world"
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```